# SourceTree Git error when pushing: error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit

Tags: git, github

I have no way to push my changes to GitHub right now. When I try to push I get the following in SourceTree (I have censored the git usernames/repo names):

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git

remote: fatal: early EOF[K
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git'
```

Things I have tried to help the issue:

```
git config --global core.compression 0
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
git config --add core.compression -1
running git repack
Cloning, copying the changed files over and pushing again
```

I am only pushing .cpp, .h and .qml files. I did have this problem previously when pushing images but that was fixed with core.compression 0.

I'm completely stumped on this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, and no solution for it yet :(

Comment: @amik Unfortunately there was no good solution for me. I had to send my local repo to a team member, who committed the changes themselves. Then I cloned fresh and it has been working since. If you are using Github, e-mail their support. It does seem to be a problem on their end.

Comment: I'd have tried cloning the repo to a different directory and then copying over the changes (being careful not to amend the files inside the `.git` folder. That often fixes unexpected Git behaviour.